# jquery blur not working on "exiting" text input even though "click" does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a custom dropdown be able to be "tabbed into" using jquery. That is, it is made of a `ul`, and I want the text input directly above it, when tabbed out of give some sort of focus to the `ul`. But for some reason this

```
var input = $("ul.dropdown_ul").prev("input");
$("#container").on("blur", input, function(){
     alert("test");
 });
```

does not work. With `click` as the event, the alert fires. But `blur` is not working.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iwicud/5/edit)

Any ideas on why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. hmm. Thanks, that seems obvious now. I'm not so hot with css selectors. is there something comprable to `prev()` that I can plug into that second argument?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm probably way off, but I thought that the element I apply `on()` to is supposed to be the closest parent that's not loaded via ajax, and then the second argument is the element that I want the event bound to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, good. Because I've used it like that about a million times and you had me worried :) Do you know how I can apply that blur event to just the input before the `ul`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #container is a div. Typically blur is used on inputs, thats why it not working. The following works fine.

```
$("#container input").on("blur", function () {
    alert("test");
});`
```

Update Regarding Comment:

If your looking to have a specific element have the on blur event. Just make sure you select it properly and apply the listener to it. I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
var $input = $("ul.dropdown_ul").prev('input')
$input.on("blur", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eKxTq/)

Comment: +1 Or more flexibly: `$("#container").on("blur", "input", function () {`

Comment: Correct, that would be more flexible.

Comment: okay, cool. Thank you. Is there anyway to modify this selector so it only applies to the input directly before the ul?

Comment: @thomas: *"Is there anyway to modify this selector so it only applies to the input directly before the ul?"* Within the handler: `if ($(this).prev('ul.dropdown_ul').length) { /* ... logic here.. */ }`.